# How to change onclick using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, onclick, dom-events

How to change `onclick` using Javascript ?

https://jsfiddle.net/749rt0m7/1/

I tried to use this code, but it does not work. How can I do it?

```
<span  onclick="test_fn('aaa,bbb')" id="xx">edit</span>
<script>
    document.getElementById('xx').onclick = "test_fn(111,222)";
</script>
```

Comment: Note that your inline attribute is passing a single argument that is a string with a comma in it, but your attempted altered version is passing two arguments that are numbers.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

There are a couple things going on here.

First of all `test_fn()` is not a function in your jsfiddle. You will need to define it in order for it to be called.

Second of all you are setting the onclick attribute to be a string not a function. You would have to set it to be a function using the code below.

```
document.getElementById('xx').onclick = function() { test_fn(111,222) };
```

Here is an example of a [working jsfiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/s676w27p/)

**UPDATE**

It looks like I misunderstood the question. If you would actually like to change the onclick attribute, as in, change what the HTML shows, you will want to use `setAttribute()`. So your code would be..

```
document.getElementById('xx').setAttribute( "onClick", "test_fn('111,222')" );
```

Here is the [updated jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sk5hdfLt/)

As a side note, like  `nnnnnn` says in a comment of the original post, using this you are passing 1 parameter through the function which is the string `111,222` when it seems that you might want to be passing two. If you would like to pass `111` as the first parameter and `222` as the second parameter, you would call the function with either `test_fn(111,222)` (passing the parameters as integers) or with `test_fn('111','222')` (passing the parameters as strings)

Comment: No when load page i want to change from `onclick="test_fn('aaa,bbb')"` to `onclick="test_fn('111,222')"`

Comment: Regarding the update, I'm not sure that you misunderstood the question so much as the OP didn't understand what they were asking for. Are there any benefits to changing the attribute to a new string rather than just assigning a function directly? I would have thought the "correct" result would be measured by which function actually gets called and with what parameters when the element is clicked, not by what the HTML "looks like", especially when "View Source" will still show the original source code.

Comment: I am unsure as to why the OP would want it done like that, however for some reason the answer that was provided to him multiples times did not seem to achieve what he wanted.

Answer (score 3):

```
document.getElementById('xx').onclick = function() {
  test_fn(111, 222);
};
```

When setting `onclick` in HTML, use a string. When setting it through JS, use a function.

Comment: No when load page i want to change from `onclick="test_fn('aaa,bbb')"` to `onclick="test_fn('111,222')"`

Comment: When i tested your code, when page i want to chage `id="my-span"` from `onclick="alert('foo')"` to `onclick="alert('baz')"` but still not work.

Comment: In my browser, the span alerts 'baz' when you click it, which is what you want, right? If it doesn't work for you, then what browser are you using? Does it support JS?

Comment: @mongkonmamiw - all of the answers are correct based on your question. Maybe try to further clarify? The function name, number of parameters and scope are all important... please describe what you're trying to do, not what you think is wrong with the code

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `onclick` to a function, that runs your code `test_fn('111,222')`:

```
<script>
  document.getElementById('xx').onclick = function() { test_fn('111,222'); }
</script>
```

Comment: No when load page i want to change from `onclick="test_fn('aaa,bbb')"` to `onclick="test_fn('111,222')"`

Comment: yes, that's what this does. `onclick` in javascript needs to be a function

Comment: @mongkonmamiw I have a sneaking suspicion you are trying to rightclick > viewsource to see the change. Well that's not how browsers work. The viewsource only shows the initial/original content returned from the server. You can see the updated onclick attribute by looking at the live DOM (use your browser's dev console to view it)

Comment: Please note that in javascript using the `.onclick` will not change the attribute in the live DOM. In order to do this you will need to use the `setAttribute` function.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where you are defining the function `test_fn` 
you are hooking the function to the element `onclick` twice in the html and in js .. only one is needed , and you need to actually define the function

```
 <span id="xx">edit</span>
 <!-- or .. not both , they are doing pretty much the same thing--> 
 <script>
   document.getElementById('xx').onclick = function(){
     console.log('clicked')
   }
 </script>
```

now you need to define `test_fn` it will get called upon clicking the element

```
function test_fn(arg1 , arg2){
  condole.log(arg1 , arg2)
}
```

note that the html `onclick` version is passing one argument and the js script version is passing two argumens.

Comment: when i tested your code https://jsfiddle.net/j2mbngq1/ `id="xx"` still `onclick="test_fn('aaa,bbb')"` not change to `onclick="test_fn('111,222')"`

Comment: edited and here is another version . http://jsbin.com/vutotar/edit?html,js,console,output