# How to make a button in html that keep pressed till i press it again?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a button that opens a popup form, but I need that when I click it again, it closes the form, there is a way to do that? I wonder if I need to destroy the button when I click it and automatically creates another equal button that closes the form.

**The button**

```
<button class="open-button" onclick="openForm()">Open Form</button>
```

**script**

```
<script>

function openForm() {
  document.getElementById("myForm").style.display = "block";
}

function closeForm() {
  document.getElementById("myForm").style.display = "none";
}

</script>
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42824309/how-to-change-onclick-using-javascript/42824347.

Comment: try `toggle` method

Answer (score 2):

The better way is to play around with styles. I have a simple code that might help you. Concentrate on the styles I am using here. It's about the `border` and the User Experience.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  document.querySelector("button").onclick = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    document.querySelector(".menu-holder").classList.toggle("active");
  };
};
```

```css
* {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  line-height: 1;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

button {
  border: 2px outset #ccc;
  padding: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

button:hover,
.menu-holder.active button {
  border-style: inset;
}

button:active, button:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.menu {
  width: 150px;
  margin: 5px 0 0;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  display: none;
}

.menu-holder.active .menu {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu-holder">
  <button>Menu</button>
  <div class="menu">Hi, I am Menu!</div>
</div>
```

**Preview**

Here's a normal mode vs. selected mode:

[image: preview]

---

**Update:** For Open / Close text, it's easier using CSS too. Check this out:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  document.querySelector("button").onclick = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    document.querySelector(".menu-holder").classList.toggle("active");
  };
};
```

```css
* {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  line-height: 1;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

button {
  border: 2px outset #ccc;
  padding: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

button:hover,
.menu-holder.active button {
  border-style: inset;
}

button:active, button:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.menu {
  width: 150px;
  margin: 5px 0 0;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  display: none;
}

.menu-holder.active .menu {
  display: block;
}

button span {
  display: none;
}
button span:first-child {
  display: inline;
}

.menu-holder.active button span {
  display: inline;
}
.menu-holder.active button span:first-child {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu-holder">
  <button><span>Open</span><span>Close</span> Menu</button>
  <div class="menu">Hi, I am Menu!</div>
</div>
```

**Preview**

Here we can see that the Open / Close is also controlled by CSS:

[image: preview]

Comment: I couldn't notice how the text changes in the code. And then I saw it - `<span>Open</span> <span> Close </span> Menu` `:-)` Excellent solution.

Comment: @sergeykuznetsov Thanks! 

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like :

```
<button id="form-button" onclick="toggleForm()">Open Form</button>

<script>

let isFormOpen = false;

function openForm() {
  document.getElementById("myForm").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("form-button").innerText = Close form;
}

function closeForm() {
  document.getElementById("myForm").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("form-button").innerText = Open form;
}

function toggleForm() {
  if (isFormOpen === true) {
    openForm();
  } else {
    closeForm();
  }
}

</script>
```

Comment: That's way complicated for a simple classList toggle.

Comment: What do you mean ?

Comment: You don't need a `isFormOpen` flag or anything.

Answer (score -1):

And this decision is from me. The `toggle()` method is used here.

```js
let button_toggle = document.querySelector('.open-close');
let form = document.querySelector('#myForm');

button_toggle.onclick = function() {
  form.classList.toggle('show');
  this.innerText = this.innerText == 'Open Form' ? 'Close Form' : 'Open Form';
}
```

```css
#myForm {
  display: none;
}

.show {
  display: block!important;
}
```

```html
<button class="open-close">Open Form</button>
<form id="myForm">
  This is text from form
</form>
```